# Unable to archive project

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, archiving

I am unable to archive my Swift project. When it's archiving, it fails at 90% of the progress. Showing the following error.

[image]

The project runs well in the simulator and on my device. But suddenly i am getting this error when archiving... It all worked well before.. Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: Try clean and archive again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this problem with cocoapods, you should edit the file "YourTarget-framework.sh" in Pods > Target Support Files > Pods-Your Target.

You need to locate this line:
`local code_sign_cmd="/usr/bin/codesign --force --sign {EXPANDED_CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY} ${OTHER_CODE_SIGN_FLAGS} --preserve-metadata=identifier,entitlements "$1""`

Replace it by :
`local code_sign_cmd="/usr/bin/codesign --force --sign ${EXPANDED_CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY} ${OTHER_CODE_SIGN_FLAGS} --preserve-metadata=identifier,entitlements '"$1"'"`

Comment: Wow.. I changed "$1"" to '"$1"'" and it worked.... How on earth is this possible? Because i even deleted my whole pods installation within the project and reinstalled it. Is this some kind a cocoapods bug?

Comment: Yes, there is a bug with cocoapods and target with space. I have searched for it before when my project didn't want to archive :)

Answer (score 0):

The path to the binary contains spaces (`[...]/ArchiveIntermediates/Trusti - Release/[...]`). This should be the problem. The error message displays the path cut before the first space.

I think you should use another product name, and adapt it in [InfoPlist.strings](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009249-110725-TPXREF135) if necessary.